# airflow xcom returns value in in sql template as a double qouted string while snowflake uses single qouted string for sql queries

Tags: mysql, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I am new to ETL and working on airflow and snowflake. I am getting max created values using python operator from mysql table and on base of the xcom of that operator I am create a csv file of snowflake data to dump only latest created at data from mysql to snowflake. The issue is airflow xcom is returning in double quotes when I pull value inside sql template. While snowflake accepts the single qoutes in its sql query. [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjm4u.png)

Following is my DAG code:

```
def defaultconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime):
        return o.__str__()


def get_max_created_timestamp(sql_table_name):
    hook = MySqlHook(MYSQL_CONN)
    check_column = f"select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '{sql_table_name}' " \
                   f"and table_schema = '{MYSQL_SCHEMA}';"
    print(hook.schema)
    data = hook.get_records(check_column)
    if any('created_at' in x for x in data):
        date_sql = f'select max(created_at) created_timestamp_max from {MYSQL_SCHEMA}.{sql_table_name}'
        (created_timestamp_max,) = hook.get_first(date_sql)
        return json.dumps(created_timestamp_max, default=defaultconverter)
        # return int(created_timestamp_max)
    else:
        return 0


default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email": [],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "template_searchpath": [TEMPLATE_SEARCHPATH, ]
}


with DAG(dag_id="lion_sense_snowflake_to_mysql_v1",
         start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
         schedule_interval="@daily",
         catchup=False,
         default_args=default_args,
         max_active_runs=1,
         ) as dag:
    dag.doc_md = DOCS

    for table in tables:
        mysql_table = table["mysql_table"]
        snowflake_table = table["snowflake_table"]
        delete_flag = table["delete"]

        get_max_timestamp_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"get_max_timestamp_{mysql_table}",
            python_callable=get_max_created_timestamp,
            op_args=[mysql_table, ],
            do_xcom_push=True,
        )

        create_snowflake_table_csv = SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id=f"create_snowflake_{snowflake_table}_table_csv",
            dag=dag,
            sql="sql/convert_snowflake_table_to_csv.sql",
            snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
            warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
            database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
            schema=SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA,
            role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE,
            params={
                "snowflake_table": snowflake_table,
                "delete_flag": delete_flag,
                "max_date": get_max_timestamp_task.output
            }
        )
```

Mysql query template:

```
copy into @S3_TKXEL_DEVEOPMENT_STAGE/airflow/{{ dag.dag_id }}/{{ ds_nodash }}/{{ params.snowflake_table }}/{{ ds_nodash }}_{{ params.snowflake_table }}.csv
from (
    select * from {{ params.snowflake_table }}
        {% if params.delete_flag %}
 where created_at > {{ params.max_date}}
        {% endif %}
    )
file_format = (TYPE = CSV, COMPRESSION = NONE, NULL_IF=(''), field_optionally_enclosed_by='"' )
OVERWRITE = TRUE
SINGLE = TRUE
MAX_FILE_SIZE=5000000000;
```

Thanks in advance for adding into my knowledge.

Comment: Can you please add how you expect the query to look like after templating? You did not specify what exactly is the error.

Comment: it seems like `created_timestamp_max` is a string, and the correct JSON encoding for a string is double quoutes. The issue is snowflake wants strings (which a date is) to be single quoted. so it seems you need to actually replace the JSON.dumps with `"'" + created_timestamp_max + "'"`

Answer (score 1):

does changing the output of `get_max_created_timestamp`:

```
def get_max_created_timestamp(sql_table_name):
    hook = MySqlHook(MYSQL_CONN)
    check_column = f"select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '{sql_table_name}' " \
                   f"and table_schema = '{MYSQL_SCHEMA}';"
    print(hook.schema)
    data = hook.get_records(check_column)
    if any('created_at' in x for x in data):
        date_sql = f'select max(created_at) created_timestamp_max from {MYSQL_SCHEMA}.{sql_table_name}'
        (created_timestamp_max,) = hook.get_first(date_sql)
        return "'" + created_timestamp_max + "'"
    else:
        return 0
```

help, as now the string will be correctly quoted for snowflakes string expectations.